# Парсинг JSON с помощью библиотеки Gson

Tags: java, json, list, gson

С сервера приходит ответ вида:

```
{
 "error":false,
 "lessons":[
  {
   "id":1,
   "discipline":"??????????",
   "group":"?11",
   "group_id":31,
   "subgroup":0,
   "lecturer":"?????? ?.?.",
   "lecturer_id":3,
   "room":"305",
   "offset":1,
   "date":"2015-05-25",
   "type":"LECTURE",
   "number":0,
   "comment":"no comments"
 },
 {
   "id":2,
   "discipline":"???. ??",
   "group":"?11",
   "group_id":31,
   "subgroup":0,
   "lecturer":"????????? ?.?.",
   "lecturer_id":4,
   "room":"406",
   "offset":2,
   "date":"2015-05-25",
   "type":"LECTURE",
   "number":0,
   "comment":"no comments"
  }
 ]
}
```

С парсингом "error" никаких проблем не возникает, но никак не получается парсить "lessons" в List.

Класс:

```
public class Lesson {
   private long id; 
   private String discipline; 
   private long group_id; 
   private int subgroup; 
   private long lecturerr_id; 
   private String room; 
   private int offset;  

   private String date; 
   private String type; 

   private int number; 
   private String comment; 



    public Lesson() {

    }

    public Lesson(long id, String discipline, int subgroup, String room, int offset, String date, String type, int number, String comment) {
        this.id = id;
        this.discipline = discipline;
        this.subgroup = subgroup;
        this.room = room;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.date = date;
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.lecturerr = lecturerr;
        this.group = group;
    }

    //геттеры и сеттеры



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lesson{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", discipline='" + discipline + '\'' +
                ", group_id=" + group_id +
                ", subgroup=" + subgroup +
                ", lecturerr_id=" + lecturerr_id +
                ", room='" + room + '\'' +
                ", offset=" + offset +
                ", date='" + date + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", number=" + number +
                ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
                ", lecturerr=" + lecturerr +
                ", group=" + group +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите Java-модели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, вкратце, у вас должно быть 2 класса.

**MainModel.class**

```
public class MainModel
{
   private boolean error; // имя должно повторять имя json-поля. Если нет, то делаем так
   @SerializedName("имя json поля - error, в данном случае")
   private boolean whatever;
   private Lesson lessons;
   public MainModel() {

   }
   /*
    ...дальше идут стандартные setter'ы и getter'ы.
}
```

**Lesson.class**

```
public class Lesson
{
   private int id;
   private String discipline;
   private String group;
   private int group_id;
   private int subgroup;
   private String lecturer;
   private int lecturer_id;
   private String room;
   private int offset;
   private String date;
   private String type;
   private int number;
   private String comment;

   public Lesson() {

   }
   /* стандартные сеттеры-геттеры.
```

Собсно парсим

```
MainModel mainModel = new Gson().fromJson(json, MainModel.class);
Log.v(TAG, "error = " + mainModel.getError();
for(Lesson lesson : mainModel.getLessons())
{
   Log.v(TAG, lessong.getDiscipline());
}
```

Comment: Так и делал, но ловил ошибку "Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"

Comment: @АртёмУлицкий ну надо было это сразу сказать)) Сказано же, что JsonSyntaxException. Ваш JSON невалидный, похоже. попробуйте сюда запихнуть http://codebeautify.org/view/jsonviewer

Comment: Valid JSON, видимо где то по коду все же ошибся

Comment: @АртёмУлицкий покажите модели. Возможно, вы все же не так массив обозначаете в модели. Сказано: ожидал встретить объект, но у вас String.

Comment: Понял ошибку, модели у меня нет как таковой, буду пробовать

Comment: Теперь Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Comment: Решил проблему, спасибо