# Парсинг json array в android с помощью gson

Tags: android, json

Прошу вашей помощи.Всё не могу понять как правильно парсить в android примерно такой json:

```
[{"Id":1, "name": name1},
{"Id":2, "name": name2},
{"Id":3, "name": name3},
{"Id":4, "name": name4},
{"Id":5, "name": name5},
{"Id":6, "name": name6},
{"Id":7, "name": name7}]
```

Нужно чтобы значения  id, name и т.д были в отдельных массивах.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ищите лучше. Даже в русском СО уже много раз задавали этот вопрос: [клац](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426973/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-gson/426975#426975) [клац2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/250280/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android)

Answer (score 1):

GSON вернет вам один массив обьектов у которых будет 3 поля, если вы изх создадите конечно. Все остальное нужно делать в коде ручками.